# combinatorics question: binary string

Tags: combinatorics, regular-expressions

I am looking for an expression that uniquely determines the following set

1. $S$ consists of binary strings starting with $0$, and the each block  $0$'s has odd length and each block of $1$ has even length
2. $S$ contains binary strings where each block of $1$'s is at most $3$ or at least $7$.

My attempt: For the first one, I get $(00)^*0\big((11)^*11(00)^*0\big)^*1^*$, does this looks good?
For the second, I was trying
$$0^*\left((1+11+111+(1111111)1^*)0^*0\right)^*(1+11+111+(1111111)1^*+e)$$But I am not quite sure if this is correct or not...does this uniquely determine the set?

Thanks!!

Comment: For the first one, you answer allows $011001$ which has a block of $0$ of even length.

Comment: For the second one, your expression looks good.

Comment: Hi, for the first one, I really mean $(00)^*0\big((11)^*11(00)^*0\big)^*1^*$, just edited... it was a stupid typo

Answer (score 1):

There is still a slight error in the first one, since the last block of $1$'s could have odd length. Thus I suggest
$$
(00)^*0\left((11)^*11(00)^*0\right)^*(11)^*
$$

Comment: Hey, yes, I am sorry, I have been really careless...It has been a long day